# How to abstract a given variable from a integerd number in CMD?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

What's the syntax of the command that could abstract a variable from a basic, integered number?

For example

by executing a batch file, a variable (like a flag) is automaticaly set to 0, grows by 1 each time another specific command is executed and peaks at 10.

I want to know at any given point, how many times this flag-variable has grown, so I could get the exact times that the affiliated command has been executed and most importantly how many times this variable still has to grow.

So, thinking purely mathematicaly, I thought of abstracting 10 out of the variable to get my answers. But i can't make this to work on CMD.

I used this exact line in the code :

```
set /a 10-variable & ( echo  executions of that command left )
```

But this only ends up showing `executions of that command left` without showing any number what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

You have a logical quirk. `set` doesn't work the way you do it.

```
@echo off
set /a variable=0
:loop
set /a variable+=1
set /a left=10-%variable%
echo %left% executions left.
if %left% gtr 0 goto :loop
echo done.
```

Alternative (using only one variable instead of two):

```
set /a left=10
:loop2
set /a left-=1
echo %left% executions left.
if %left% gtr 0 goto :loop2
echo done.
```

Note: `set /a var+=1` is just a short form of `set /a var=%var%+1`